# Converting 3D graphics primitives to 3D image data

Tags: graphics3d, geometry, image3d, discretization

My goal is to produce a 3D dataset, from a scene of simple transformed shapes. The idea is that this data serves as a ground truth for some tomographic reconstruction problems. (For this, it is especially nice that with Mathematica, `Ellipsoid`, `Cuboid` and other 3D primitives remain algebraic up to the point of discretization.)

Ideally, I would like to partition the 3D space into voxels (small cuboids), and compute per voxel how much of it is filled by a shape. This does not have to be very precise, I'm happy already if the value is $1$ if it contains something and $0$ otherwise.

However, I do not manage to get the shapes into a discrete dataset of values. So far, I tried something simple:

```
B = Ball[{10,10,10}, 2];
reg = TransformedRegion[B, ShearingTransform[Pi/5, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]]
DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[reg]];
```

which produces a triangular mesh (instead of a uniform) for an ellipsoid (sheared ball).

For 2D problems I managed to get grid data from converting the `Graphics` to grayscale, and subsequently to `ImageData`. In 3D that doesn't work.

It seems like a relatively simple thing to do, but after a few hours of bugging the documentation, I still did not find a solution. All suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a full-dimensional discretization of `reg`? Then try `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg]` or `DiscretizeRegion[reg]`. `Graphics3D` objects represent only the surfaces of the regions (for performance reasons).

Comment: Have you seen `RegionImage[]`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, that is good to know!

Comment: @J.M. Wow! That looks very promising, how could I have missed that! Thanks!

Comment: You could combine it with `ImageMesh[]` if you want to see a voxelization.

Comment: I couldn't have hoped for something simpler and more intuitive than this, it works perfectly.

Comment: I can't post pics, so: please answer your own question if you were able to figure out how to use them for your `reg`.

Comment: Will do. Of course I'd also accept an answer without images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, a judicious combination of  `RegionImage[]` and `ImageMesh[]` will yield suitable voxelizations of regions. Applied to the OP's example:

```
reg = TransformedRegion[Ball[{10, 10, 10}, 2], 
                        ShearingTransform[π/5, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]];

ImageMesh[RegionImage[DiscretizeRegion[reg]]]
```

[image: voxelized ellipsoid]